# C++/CLR application that starts a process and injects a DLL into it only works when not ran as admin

Tags: c#, c++, .net, clr, uac

So, this is an odd one.

I have a .NET application that loads a C++/CLR DLL which, in turn, starts a process (Using CreateProcess) and injects a DLL into it (using the remote thread method). However, the newly created process (which is a game) has completely different textures when you start the .NET application as administrator, and when you invoke it as a normal user. Its textures are contained in files inside the game's root directory. My process creation code works fine if I build it as a standalone program -- without CLR -- and run it, so it can't be that.

What could be the cause of this? It has nothing to do with the game that I'm starting, I'm sure. The directory the game reads stuff from is admin-only, so naturally, running the .NET application as admin should give me access. But I get the exact opposite -- it only works when I run it without admin rights.

Comment: Are you saying the game folder is supposed to be totally inaccessible without admin rights?

Comment: Actually, no, something even odder is happening. I've just given all users all permissions to the folder, and I get the same thing.

Comment: Any use of TEMP directories or other folders that might be different according to the user running the application?

Comment: Nope, nope, files are located in Program Files. This is honestly above me.

Comment: One thing to try is doing a Process Monitor run for the two cases, then compare the logs. This should show you where there's a divergence in the behavior from the 2 different modes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting myself from another question :

Some locations, like "Program Files", are protected on the latest versions of Windows. If your program is not run as administrator and try to access a protected location, the read/write operations will be silently redirected to C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\MY\FOLDER\PATH. Running your program as admin should correct this wherever it is located.

Take a look at this location, you will see if the problem comes from here.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work when I DO run it as admin, but works when I don't.

Comment: @NikolaYanakiev Yes I read that. That doesn't mean anything. Maybe the right files are actually in the virtual store. That's why I suggest to take a look to be sure.

Comment: Right, there were some different files in the VirtualStore. I removed them, and it now replaced the files in the game folder with default ones (most likely a game function). What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @NikolaYanakiev The best way would be to let it be. If you control the entire read/write chain, just either run as admin or don't and don't change. Assuming you don't control the entire read/write chain, use the same mode as the game. If the game use the virtual store and you really want to run as admin, retrieve the virtual store location and use it.  Though I don't know how to retrieve this path programmatically.

Comment: @NikolaYanakiev Maybe you can go with "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\VirtualStore", it will probably always work.

Comment: Right, managed to fix it manually by removing the whole game folder inside VirtualStore, then starting the game, then it replacing original files with defaults, then replacing those files with modified ones. Now, to figure out how to solve this programmatically...

Comment: @NikolaYanakiev Be aware that if the game uses the virtual store, files in "Program Files" will never be updated by the game. It may be important depending on what you want to do.

Comment: Well, seeing as the files it accesses aren't being modified by it, moving the files inside VirtualStore to the actual game folder should suffice... right?

Comment: @NikolaYanakiev Maybe, but I don't think it is a good idea anyway. The purpose of the virtual store is to separate users. Each user will be able to play the game independently, because files are redirected to the virtual store, which is user-dependent. Copying back the files defeats the purpose. Also, maybe the files aren't modified now, but a patch could. I would prefer accessing the same files as the game, using the %USERPROFILE% path, and retrieve the actually used path. Also, maybe the game is using a registry key to locate its folder, you may want to take this into account.

Comment: The problem is my application places a file inside the game's directory and injects DLLs, and both of these operations require administrator privileges as the game's directory is inside Program Files. But at the same time, when you run the game with administrator privileges, it doesn't work properly. So every time there's an update, the end-user has to start the application as admin, then close it and restart it without admin. You can see the issue here, right.

Comment: @NikolaYanakiev Do you need to run the game as admin ? I think you shouldn't anyway. The best way is probably to place your files in the virtual store by yourself, either by locating the path yourself (with %USERPROFILE% and all), or by launching a sub process as non-admin, that will do the job and automagically place the files in the right place.

Comment: Yeah, I moved all of the application files to AppData, don't need to run as admin now. Issue solved, thanks.